# PythonMagickWand Shepards Distortion (ctypes LP_c_double problem)

Tags: python, imagemagick, ctypes, magickwand

I am trying to use [PythonMagickWand](http://public.procoders.net/PythonMagickWand/docs/html/index.html) to use a [Shepards distortion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards) on an image. You can also see [the source of distort.c](http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/ImageMagick/trunk/magick/distort.c) that is used by ImageMagick.

PythonMagickWand does not by default support Shepards distortion. To fix this, I added in:

`ShepardsDistortion = DistortImageMethod(15)`

to line 544 of PythonMagickWand ([See here for my modified PythonMagicWand](http://pastebin.com/bVjCL1w4)). The 15 pointer is in reference to [distort.h](http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/ImageMagick/trunk/magick/distort.h) (line 51) of the MagickWand source in which ShepardsDistortion is the 15th item on the list. This fits with all of the other supported distortion methods.

Now, something that I may be doing wrong is presuming that the existing distortion methods that are supported by PythonMagickWand use the same type of arguments as the Shepards. They might not but I do not know how I can tell. I know that [distort.c](http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/ImageMagick/trunk/magick/distort.c) is doing the work, but I can't work out if the arguments it takes in are the same or different.

I have the following code (snippet):

```
from PythonMagickWand import *
from ctypes import *

arrayType = c_double * 8  
pointsNew = arrayType()
pointsNew[0] = c_double(eyeLeft[0])
pointsNew[1] = c_double(eyeLeft[1])
pointsNew[2] = c_double(eyeLeftDest[0])
pointsNew[3] = c_double(eyeLeftDest[1])
pointsNew[4] = c_double(eyeRight[0])
pointsNew[5] = c_double(eyeRight[1])
pointsNew[6] = c_double(eyeRightDest[0])
pointsNew[7] = c_double(eyeRightDest[1])

MagickWandGenesis()
wand = NewMagickWand()
MagickReadImage(wand,path_to_image+'image_mod.jpg')
MagickDistortImage(wand,ShepardsDistortion, 8, pointsNew, False)
MagickWriteImage(wand,path_to_image+'image_mod22.jpg')
```

I get the following error:

`MagickDistortImage(wand,ShepardsDistortion, 8, pointsNew, False)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_double instance instead of list`

I am aware that pointsNew is the wrong way of providing the arguments.. But I just don't know what is the right format. This is an example distort command that works when run in Terminal:

`convert image.jpg -virtual-pixel Black -distort Shepards 121.523809524,317.79638009 141,275  346.158730159,312.628959276 319,275  239.365079365,421.14479638 232,376  158.349206349,483.153846154 165,455  313.015873016,483.153846154 300,455  0,0 0,0  0,571.0 0,571.0  464.0,571.0 464.0,571.0  0,571.0 0,571.0 image_out.jpg`

So I guess the question is: How do I create a list of c_doubles that will be accepted by PythonMagickWand? **Or** is my hack to add Shepards Distortion into PythonMagickWand completely wrong?

I basically need to re-create the terminal command. I have got it working by using subprocess to run the command from Python but that is not how I want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NeedMoreBeer](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/ccofm/hi_pyreddit_i_asked_a_question_on_stack_overflow/c0rnlwf) on [Reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com/):

```
from PythonMagickWand import *
from ctypes import *

arrayType = c_double * 8  
pointsNew = arrayType()
pointsNew[0] = c_double(121.523809524)
pointsNew[1] = c_double(317.79638009)
pointsNew[2] = c_double(141)
pointsNew[3] = c_double(275) 
pointsNew[4] = c_double(346.158730159)
pointsNew[5] = c_double(312.628959276)
pointsNew[6] = c_double(319)
pointsNew[7] = c_double(275)

ShepardsDistortion = DistortImageMethod(14)

MagickWandGenesis()
wand = NewMagickWand()
MagickReadImage(wand,'/home/user/image.png')
MagickDistortImage(wand,ShepardsDistortion, 8, pointsNew, False)
MagickWriteImage(wand,'/home/user/image_mod22.jpg')
```

More specifically for me, it was the following line:

```
ShepardsDistortion = DistortImageMethod(14)
```

That fixed it for me! Thanks again to **NeedMoreBeer** from [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the function is expecting a pointer (`LP_c_double`), but all you have is an array.

You'll need to explicitly cast your array to a pointer, for the purposes of passing it *as* a pointer to the external function:

```
>>> arr = (c_double * 8)()
>>> arr # just an array...
<__main__.c_double_Array_8 object at 0x1004ad050>
>>> arr[0] = 5
# ...
>>> cast(arr, POINTER(c_double)) # now it's the right type
<__main__.LP_c_double object at 0x1004ad0e0>
>>> cast(arr, POINTER(c_double))[0]
5.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I was. I just wrote out a simplified snippet and forgot to add that import in. I've edited my post to fit that now!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. The function *does* accept this as input.. *However*, it doesn't do anything. I failed to mention my modification of PythonMagickWand before which is undoubtedly an important hint to why this isn't working. I've modified my post to reflect in more detail what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is OT, but:

I really liked python magick wand, but when I used it on 600+ images there was a memory leak somewhere, which ate all the memory in the (32 bit) machine.  I was inclined to think possibly in ImageMagick itself, but I might've been wrong.

In the end I found out that:

GraphicsMagick is a port of an earlier version of ImageMagick; but because ImageMagick changes their API a lot, PythonMagickWant won't work with GraphicsMagick.

GraphicsMagick, also seems to be faster than ImageMagick (using better multitasking).

In order to get my script working quickly, in a few days I changed it so that instead of using ImageMagick, the script loaded the gimp, which then ran my script using python-scriptfu.
Everything seemed to work OK.

If it works for you, then use it; also the PythonMagickWand guy is really helpful + the bindings are nice.